# Check if string does not contain URL segment and match it

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

How to check if URL string does not contain the following string: `test/test/posts/search/1234567`, so that when I provide the following URL: `test/test/1234567` the `match` function would return: `["test/test/1234567", "test/test/", "", "1234567"]`?

**Update:**

If I provide `/posts/search` in URL I would like to omit this regex in `re.test(url)` function.

```js
// var url = "test/test/posts/search/1234567"; // desired result: null
var url = "test/test/1234567"; // result: ["test/test/1234567", "test/test/", undefined, "1234567"]
var urlPrefix = 'test/test/';
var re = new RegExp('(' + urlPrefix + ')(posts\/search\/)([0-9]+)', 'i');
console.log(url.match(re));
```

Comment: Can the output look like `["test/test/1234567", "test/test/", undefined, "1234567"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, you just need to make the second capturing group optional with `?` quantifier meaning *0 or 1 occurrence, greedy*:

```js
var url = "test/test/posts/search/1234567"; // result: null
var urlPrefix = 'test/test/';
if (!url.includes("posts/search/")) {
   var re = new RegExp('(' + urlPrefix + ')(posts/search/)?([0-9]+)', 'i');
   //                                                     ^    
   console.log(url.match(re));
}
else {
console.log(url + " contains 'posts/search/'!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to add, that I would like to omit in `test()` function url that contains `posts/search/` if it is easy how to achieve this?

Comment: Please check the update. I think `includes` is a nice alternative to regex here.